# Upload image as bytearray in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I try to upload a file in a form in ASP.NET, my form is

```
    <form metod="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FormPage">
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" />
        <input type="file" asp-for="Image" accept="image/*" />
    </form>
```

and the model is:

```
class MyCLass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set }
}
```

but when I select a file for the image-input, I get that it is not a valid input when i submit. Are there ways to solve it?

Comment: what file type are you trying to upload?

Comment: I've tried jpg and png, and niether worked

Comment: have you considered using the IFormFile Type to receive the file

Answer (score 0):

But, why do you care how or what the file being up-loaded is?

I mean, with any simple fileupload control, once the post-back has occured, you have the "in memory" file, and you are 100% free to convert to a byte() array at that point time. Why even bother or have the client side have to do any of that mumbo jumbo anyway?

I mean this:

```
        <h3>Select file to up-load</h3>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdGO" runat="server" Text="Up-load"
         OnClick="cmdGO_Click" />
```

And then code behind:

```
    protected void cmdGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            byte[] FileAsBytes;
            FileAsBytes = (byte[])FileUpload1.FileBytes;

            // do whatever with the byte array
            MyCLass cFile = new MyCLass();
            cFile.Id = 134;
            cFile.Name = "Hello";
            cFile.Image = FileAsBytes;

        }
    }
```

or probably better yet:

```
protected void cmdGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        // do whatever with the byte array
        MyCLass cFile = new MyCLass();
        cFile.Id = 134;
        cFile.Name = "Hello";
        cFile.Image = (byte[])FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

So, you can easy convert the file to bytes[] in the server side code.